# How to get offset() relative to parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This gives me the position of some element from the left edge of the main window:

```
$('#bar').offset().left;
```

If that element is situated inside some other element and I wanted the position of #bar relative to #foo (it's parent), how can I get that?

```
<style>
#foo { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }
#foo #bar { width: 50px; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>

<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar"></span>
</div>
```

I saw that there is a function called `offsetParent()` but when console logged it doesn't seem like this function has any properties called `left` or `x`. So not sure if that can be used to get what I need.

So in my example above the offset should be something around 125px from the parent's edge rather than some thousands of pixels from the main windows edge.

Comment: Get the parent's left offset and do a subtraction?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use the position() method.

```
$('#bar').position().left;
```

Comment: sweet I love simple solutions.

Comment: anyway to go beyond parent like grand parent...so i am targeting li than how do i skip ui and go for div which has ui in it

Comment: Note that the parent should be `position: relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: To clarify alexmngn's comment, .position() only works if the parent is position relative, absolute, or fixed.  Niet the Dark Absol's answer doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 49):

It's simple enough: get the offset of the element and substract the offset of its parent.

```
var elem = $("#bar");
var offset = elem.offset().left - elem.parent().offset().left;
```

Comment: +1 This works well to determine position of the cursor relative to parent element, when the child element is transformed with webkit-transform matrix

Comment: For more universal solution it is better to use .offsetParent (instead of .parent ) to get closest **positioned** parent.

Comment: @krummens take a look at the comments to the accepted answer, it has limitations

Comment: This is a correct solution as works with `display: flex`

Answer (score 24):

**Position within a div relative to its parent:**

*In my case, when scroll changed the calculated offset also changed and it shouldn't so i ended up using pure javascript which is quicker anyway...*

**element.get(0).offsetTop**

*Other variation like Left is also possible **element.get(0).offsetLeft***

**Conclusion**

element.offset().top or position() are not optimal for position relative cases.

Comment: element.get(0).offsetLeft -> Only this one worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice solution, maybe a more detailed explaination such as what's .get(0) does would have made this perfect. I know what it does, it gets the first dom element of the jquery collection.

Answer (score 3):

```
offsetLeft = $('#bar').position().left;
offsetTop = $('#bar').position().top;
```

Comment: The strange thing is that if delete position:relative on the container (line 6 of the css) position() behaves the same as offset(). See this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ciroxxx/ut7ord0a/1/