# how to make banner image draggable inside div then save position

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, draggable

I've seen lots of questions and answers around how to do this but I am very stuck how I implement this into my webpage. I have a div named "banner" that contains an image drawn from a custom field that is on all my artist pages as a banner for each page. I would like to be able to drag this image inside the div and to save it's position. (I only want this function for myself, not visitors to the website) AKA Facebook page cover image.. This would allow me to add an image that is bigger than the div container to my custom field and for me to edit how this is showing inside the div.

This demonstates what I want to do- http://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/
but i don't understand where i put these codes in my wordpress files and how to make this work for me.. I only want this on my artist pages, and therefore using my single-artists.php template..

Here is my php code-

```
<?php
// artist download start
//  if ( isset($_GET['download']) ) {
//      header('Content-type: application/mp3');
//      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($_GET['download']));
//      readfile( $_GET['download'] );
//  }
// artist download end

get_header(); 
global $cs_transwitch,$prettyphoto_flag;
$prettyphoto_flag = "true";
    $cs_artist = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_artist", true);
    if ( $cs_artist <> "" ) {
        $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_artist);
            $cs_layout = $xmlObject->cs_layout;
            $cs_sidebar_left = $xmlObject->cs_sidebar_left;
            $cs_sidebar_right = $xmlObject->cs_sidebar_right;
    }
        if ( $cs_layout == "left" ) {
            $cs_layout = "two-thirds column right";
            $show_sidebar = $cs_sidebar_left;
        }
        else if ( $cs_layout == "right" ) {
            $cs_layout = "two-thirds column left";
            $show_sidebar = $cs_sidebar_right;
        }
        else $cs_layout = "sixteen columns left";
?>
<div id="banner">
<div id="bannercontent"><?php
list($src, $w, $h) = get_custom_field('banner:to_image_array');
?>
<img src="<?php print $src; ?>" width="100%" />
</div></div>
<script>$( "#bannercontent" ).draggable({
stop: function(){
    alert('top offset: ' + $('#bannercontent').offset().top + ' left offset: ' + $('#bannercontent').offset().left);
}
});</script>
<div class="clear:both;"></div>
        <div id="container" class="container row">
            <div role="main" class="<?php echo $cs_layout;?>" >
                <?php
                    /* Run the loop to output the post.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called loop-single.php and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    //get_template_part( 'loop', 'single_cs_artist' );
                ?>
                        <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php
                            //showing meta start
                            $cs_artist = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cs_artist", true);
                            if ( $cs_artist <> "" ) {
                                $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_artist);
                                    $cs_layout = $xmlObject->cs_layout;
                                    $cs_sidebar_left = $xmlObject->cs_sidebar_left;
                                    $cs_sidebar_right = $xmlObject->cs_sidebar_right;
                                    $artist_release_date = $xmlObject->artist_release_date;
                                    $artist_social_share = $xmlObject->artist_social_share;
                                    $artist_buy_amazon = $xmlObject->artist_buy_amazon;
                                    $artist_buy_apple = $xmlObject->artist_buy_apple;
                                    $artist_buy_groov = $xmlObject->artist_buy_groov;
                                    $artist_buy_cloud = $xmlObject->artist_buy_cloud;
                            }
                            //showing meta end
                        ?>
                            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                <h1 class="heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                <div class="in-sec">
                                    <?php
                                    // getting featured image start
                                        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID );
                                        if ( $image_id <> "" ) {
                                            //$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, array(208,208),true);
                                            $image_url = cs_attachment_image_src($image_id, 208, 208);
                                                $image_url = $image_url;
                                            //$image_url_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full',true);
                                            $image_url_full = cs_attachment_image_src($image_id, 0, 0);
                                                $image_url_full = $image_url_full;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            $image_url = get_template_directory_uri()."/images/admin/no_image.jpg";
                                            $image_url_full = get_template_directory_uri()."/images/admin/no_image.jpg";
                                        }
                                            //$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID );
                                            //$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, array(208,198),true);
                                            //$image_url_full = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'full',true);
                                    // getting featured image end
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="light-box artist-tracks artist-detail <?php if($image_id == "") echo "no-img-found";?> ">
<div id="main-container">
<div id="leftcolumn">
                                            <a rel="prettyPhoto" name="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php echo $image_url_full?>" class="thumb" >

                                                <?php echo "<img src='".$image_url."' />";?>
                                            </a>
<br>
<br>
<div id="inpostgallery"><?php echo do_shortcode('[inpost_gallery thumb_width="104" thumb_height="104" post_id="' . get_the_ID() . '" thumb_margin_left="0" thumb_margin_bottom="0" thumb_border_radius="2" thumb_shadow="0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" js_play_delay="3000" id="" random="0" group="0" border="" type="yoxview" show_in_popup="0" artist_cover="" artist_cover_width="200" artist_cover_height="200" popup_width="800" popup_max_height="600" popup_title="Gallery"][/inpost_gallery]'); ?></div>
</div>
<div id="rightcolumn">
                                            <div class="desc">
                                                <p style="font-size:12px;"><span class="bold" style="text-transform:uppercase; color:#262626;"><?php _e('Categories', CSDOMAIN); ?> :</span> 
                                                  <?php
                                                    /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                                                    $before_cat = " ".__( '',CSDOMAIN );
                                                    $categories_list = get_the_term_list ( get_the_id(), 'artist-category', $before_cat, ', ', '' );
                                                    if ( $categories_list ): printf( __( '%1$s', CSDOMAIN ),$categories_list ); endif; '</p>'; 
                                                  ?>
                                                </p>
<br>
<h5><?php print_custom_field('stars:formatted_list', array('<li><img src="http://www.entertaininc.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/gold-star-graphic-e1441218522835.png">[+value+]</li>','<ul>[+content+]</ul>') );
 ?></h5><br />
<h2><strong>Price</strong> <?php print_custom_field('price'); ?></h2> <br />
<h2><strong>Location</strong> <?php echo do_shortcode('[gmw_post_info info="city, country" divider=","]'); ?></h2><br />
                                                         <h4><?php _e('Description', CSDOMAIN); ?></h4>
                                                        <div class='txt rich_editor_text'>
                                                            <?php 
                                                                the_content();

                                                            ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', CSDOMAIN ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
</div></div>
                                             </div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="in-sec">
                                    <div class="artist-opts">
                                        <div class="share-artist">
                                        <?php 
                                            $cs_social_share = get_option("cs_social_share");                           
                                            if($cs_social_share != ''){
                                              $xmlObject_artist = new SimpleXMLElement($cs_social_share);
                                                if($artist_social_share == 'Yes'){
                                                    social_share(); 
                                                 }?>                        
                                            <?php }?>   
                                        </div>
                                        <?php if($artist_buy_amazon != '' or $artist_buy_apple != '' or $artist_buy_groov != '' or $artist_buy_cloud != ''){?>
                                        <div class="availble">
                                            <h4><?php if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Buy This',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('buy_now', 'Buy This'); }?></h4>
                                            <?php
                                                if ( $artist_buy_amazon <> "" ) echo ' <a target="_blank" href="'.$artist_buy_amazon.'" class="amazon-ind">&nbsp;<span>';if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Amazon',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('amazon', 'Amazon'); }  echo '</span></a> ';
                                                if ( $artist_buy_apple <> "") echo ' <a target="_blank" href="'.$artist_buy_apple.'" class="apple-ind">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Apple',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('itunes', 'iTunes'); }  echo '</span></a> ';
                                                if ( $artist_buy_groov <> "") echo ' <a target="_blank" href="'.$artist_buy_groov.'" class="grooveshark-ind">&nbsp;<span>';  if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('GrooveShark',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('grooveshark', 'GrooveShark'); }  echo '</span></a> ';
                                                if ( $artist_buy_cloud <> "") echo ' <a target="_blank" href="'.$artist_buy_cloud.'" class="soundcloud-ind">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('SoundCloud',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('soundcloud', 'SoundCloud '); } echo '</span></a> ';
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php }?>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php  
                                foreach ( $xmlObject as $track ){
                                    if ( $track->getName() == "track" ) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="in-sec">
                                    <?php 
                                    enqueue_alubmtrack_format_resources();
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="artist-tracks light-box">
                                        <?php 
                                            $counter = 0;
                                            foreach ( $xmlObject as $track ){
                                                $counter++;
                                                if ( $track->getName() == "track" ) {
                                                    echo "<div class='track'>";
                                                    echo "<h5>";
                                                    echo $artist_track_title = $track->artist_track_title;
                                                    echo "</h5>";
                                                    echo "<ul>";
                                                        if ($track->artist_track_playable == "Yes") {
                                                            echo '
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <div class="cp-container cp_container_'.$counter.'">
                                                                        <ul class="cp-controls">
                                                                            <li><a style="display: block;" href="#" class="cp-play" tabindex="1">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Play',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('play', 'Play'); } echo '</span></a></li>
                                                                            <li><a href="#" class="cp-pause" style="display: none;" tabindex="1">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Pause',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('pause', 'Pause'); } echo '</span></a></li>
                                                                        </ul>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" class="cp-jplayer jquery_jplayer_'.$counter.'">
                                                                        <img style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;" id="jp_poster_0">
                                                                        <audio src="'.$track->artist_track_mp3_url.'" preload="metadata" ></audio>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <script>
                                                                        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                                                                            var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer(".jquery_jplayer_'.$counter.'",
                                                                                {
                                                                                    mp3: "'.$track->artist_track_mp3_url.'"
                                                                                }, {
                                                                                    cssSelectorAncestor: ".cp_container_'.$counter.'",
                                                                                    swfPath: "'.get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/frontend/Jplayer.swf",
                                                                                    wmode: "window",
                                                                                    supplied: "mp3"
                                                                                });
                                                                        });
                                                                    </script>
                                                                </li>
                                                            ';
                                                        }
                                                        if ($track->artist_track_downloadable == "Yes"){ echo '<li><a href="'.$track->artist_track_mp3_url.'" class="download">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Download',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('download', 'Download'); } echo '</span></a></li>'; }
                                                        if ($track->artist_track_lyrics <> "") { echo '<li><a href="#lyrics'.$counter.'" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]" title="'.$artist_track_title.'" class="lyrics">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Lyrics',CSDOMAIN); }else{ echo __CS('lyrics', 'Lyrics'); } echo '</span></a></li>';}
                                                        if ($track->artist_track_buy_mp3 <> ""){ echo '<li><a href="'.$track->artist_track_buy_mp3.'" class="buysong">&nbsp;<span>'; if($cs_transwitch =='on'){ _e('Buy&nbsp;Song',CSDOMAIN); }else{  echo __CS('buy_now', 'Buy&nbsp;Song'); } echo '</span></a></li>';}


                                                    echo "</ul>";
                                                    echo '
                                                        <div id="lyrics'.$counter.'" style="display:none;">
                                                            '.str_replace("\n","</br>",$track->artist_track_lyrics).'
                                                        </div>
                                                    ';
                                                    echo "</div>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                } 
                                ?>  
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ) :?>
                                <div class="in-sec" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                    <div class="about-author">
                                        <div class="avatars">
                                            <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'PixFill_author_bio_avatar_size', 53 ) ); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="desc">
                                            <h5><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php _e('About', CSDOMAIN); ?> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></h5>
                                            <p class="txt">
                                                <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; // end of the loop. ?>
                        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            </div>
            <?php if( $cs_layout != "sixteen columns left" and isset($show_sidebar) ) { ?>
            <!--Sidebar Start-->
                <div class="one-third column left">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar($show_sidebar) ) : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>   
                </div>            
            <!--Sidebar Ends-->  
            <?php }?>
            <div class="clear"></div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery UI library (draggable) - https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
And then read the offset of the div or so

Comment: thanks for the quick comment @manchary I have read this webpage for the jquery but as someone who's new to this I don't really understand what code i need to add and where in my files..

Comment: Which version of wordpress are you using? It can have Jquery UI already included, check out your loaded scripts, or try this code `$('#myDiv').draggable()` in the console of the elements inspector. If it's not included you will have to include it using `wp_register_scripts` or hardcoding it to the header(not recommended)

Comment: 4.2.4 Yes it does I think.. includes there are loads of jquery files including draggable.min.js. But how do I add this function to my banner in my php template.. Sorry I've never used a jquery function before without copying existing code.. As i mentioned above this link shows a tutorial that does exactly what i want to do.. http://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/ but it doesn't mention where you paste the codes.. as in which files you paste it in.. very confused

Comment: the all jquery part is going to your template file or your `main.js` file (if you have it). And there is the php part with some crop and resize class included, idk about that, you can resize it all from the front-end and than just save the edits using php

Comment: thanks a lot. So would I put the html in my template php file? and where would I put the Javascript? Sorry, i'm sure this is all basic stuff :s

Comment: the jquery and html part goes into the template php file, for example, it can be single.php (the single post template file in wordpress default themes) 
the jquery code must be included in the html `<script> jquery code here </script>` tags
Make sure that not to include html tags inside of the `<?php ... ?>` code

Comment: hmm. i've tried but when visiting the webpage isn't dragging.. please see my updated code above..

Comment: try running the jquery code when document is ready, like so `<script>$(function(){ ...your draggable code here... });</script>`

Comment: using the following code has made the picture draggable.. <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){ $( "#bannercontent" ).draggable({
stop: function(){
    alert('top offset: ' + $('#bannercontent').offset().top + ' left offset: ' + $('#bannercontent').offset().left);
}
}); });</script> So getting there.. problems i have still.. once dragged the photo is now showing outside of the "banner" div even though i have overflow: hidden on.. and when i refresh the page the picture isn't staying in position..

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement look at this example, there is `view code` button where you can see the code. you need to use this option `$('#myDiv').draggable({ containment: "#myDivParent" })` after you have moved the picture you need to get its positioning parameters and then save it into some custom_fields of the post (for example), and if you will reload the page read that custom_fields and apply positioning to a div

Comment: ok thanks will give it a go. also i only want me as admin to have the ability to drag the image.. is there a way to do this?

Comment: i have managed to add custom fields to position the "banner content" however the offset alerts aren't giving me the right figures. I think they are giving the figures relative to the top left of the document and not in relation to the container div "banner" trying to change the offset alerts to give values in relation to the "banner" div but so far unsucessful..

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin - link number 1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954931/how-to-get-offset-relative-to-parent-in-jquery - link number 2

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a jquery plugin named [draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/). See the event dragMove or dragEnd. Hope it helps.